# Update task list after collecting data from a user in Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: workflow

I'm attempting to update a value in a sharepoint task after collecting data from a user after it has been completed in sharepoint designer. What I am doing is creating a "Collect Data from a User Task" this returns an ID for the task that was completed and I output that to a workflow variable. The next step I'm attempting to set a value in the Task that was completed. From my understanding I should be able to use this ID to perform a lookup on the task list using the ID that I recieved by collecting the form. Everytime I attempt to do this though it fails in error with a Description saying "Error updating a list item". Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it by having another list be an "audit" list that would be created at every step of the workflow that way a full approval history is created for each item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "set field" action. The value is looked up from Associated Task List.
choose the value from the task, and choose "ID" to lookup task list. The value used to lookup is the output of "Collect Data from a User Task"